# Low performance of layout params animation in Android

Tags: android, animation, kotlin

Currently I'm animating the width of an object with following code:

```
val animation = ValueAnimator.ofInt(layoutParams.width, value)
           .setDuration(duration)
    animation.interpolator = interpolator ?: LinearInterpolator()
    animation.start()
    animation.addUpdateListener {
        val animatedValue = it.animatedValue as Int
        layoutParams.width = animatedValue
        requestLayout()
    }
    animation.addListener(object: Animator.AnimatorListener {
        override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animator?) {}
        override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animator?) {
            endHandler?.invoke()
        }
        override fun onAnimationCancel(p0: Animator?) {}
        override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animator?) {}
    })
```

However, animation is very laggy even on simple layouts. Is there any way to improve the performance of layoutParams-changing animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've asked this question at the GDD 2017 in Cracow on the "Office Hours" and they've told me to look at the Nick Butcher's App -> Plaid.io. It is definitely worth checking out if you are interesting in Android's animations.

Here is the link:

https://github.com/nickbutcher/plaid

We did it and we saw that he often is using

```
animation.willChangeBounds = true
```

and that fixed our problem with laggy animations <3

Answer (score 0):

Use `animation.setTarget(viewToAnimate)` method to animate target view.

I haven't tested it, let me know it works or not.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help, although thank you for your input!

Comment: @RafałPłonka did you remove `addUpdateListener `?

Comment: No, and it won't work if I do that, because the width is being updated in it.

Comment: @RafałPłonka so want to change width of the view right?

Comment: @RafałPłonka try removing `requestLayout() ` line and check if it works.